# how can i push back an in into a vector with different data type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have two classes, one called "`OrganisationRecord`" and the other called "`PayrollProcessing`". "`OrganisationRecord`" contains the name occupation and department of an employee.

```
class OrganisationRecord
{
private:
public:
    string name;
    string occupation;
    string department;
};

class PayrollProcessing
{
private:
    ifstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputfile;
    vector<OrganisationRecord> OrganisationRecords;
public:
    void loadOrganisationRecords(string filename);
    void displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE(double salary);

    //GTE = greater than or equal to
};
```

within "`PayrollProcessing`" are two member functions; "`loadOrganisationRecords`" and "`displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE`" the code for which are:

```
void PayrollProcessing::loadOrganisationRecords(string filename)
{
    inputfile.open(ORGANISATIONALRECORDSFILE);

    if (!inputfile)
    {
        cout << "the organisation records file does not exist!" << endl;
        return;
    }
        OrganisationRecord _organisationrecord;
        int employeenumber;

        while (inputfile >> employeenumber)
        {
            inputfile.ignore();
            getline(inputfile, _organisationrecord.name);
            getline(inputfile, _organisationrecord.occupation);
            getline(inputfile, _organisationrecord.department);

            OrganisationRecords.push_back(_organisationrecord);
        }

        inputfile.close();
}

void PayrollProcessing::displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE(double salary)
    {
        unsigned int count;
        salary = SALARY;

        if (salary < 0)
        {
            cout << "no record match this criteria!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        for (count = 0; count < PayrollRecords.size(); count++)
        {
            if (PayrollRecords[count].salary >= salary)
            {
                cout << "=============================================" << endl;
                cout << "Employeenumber: " << endl << endl;
                cout << "Name: " << OrganisationRecords[count].name << endl;
                cout << "Adress: " <<  HRRecords[count].address << endl;
                cout << "Department: " << OrganisationRecords[count].department << endl;
                cout << "Salary: " << PayrollRecords[count].salary << endl;
                cout << "=============================================" << endl;
                cout << OrganisationRecords.size();
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

how can i implicitly make the employee number available for display in "`displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE`".

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Also, where is `PayrollRecords` even defined? Does this code compile?

Comment: basically I want to store the employee number into the organisation records vector

Comment: the code compiles perfectly, I just cant figure out a way to display employee number

Comment: According to your reading code, *every* organization record has an employee number.  So just add a field for that value to your `OrganisationRecord` class, then you will have access to it in `displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE()`.

Comment: I was told not to modify the classes, been trying t figure it out all week

Comment: Told by whom? That is information you should have included in your question. You can't solve this issue without modifying at least one of classes, either by adding a new field to `OrganisationRecord`, or another `vector` to `PayrollProcessing`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your reading code, *every* organization record has an employee number.  So simply add a field for that value to your `OrganisationRecord` class, then you will have access to it in `displayEmployeeOfSalaryGTE()`, eg:

```
class OrganisationRecord
{
public:
    int employeeNumber; // <-- add this
    ...
};

...

void PayrollProcessing::loadOrganisationRecords(string filename)
{
    ...

    int employeeNumber;
    OrganisationRecord _organisationrecord;

    while (inputfile >> employeeNumber)
    {
        inputfile.ignore();
        _organisationrecord.employeeNumber = employeeNumber // <-- add this
        ...
    }

    ...
}

...

cout << "EmployeeNumber: " << OrganisationRecords[count].employeeNumber << endl;
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without modifying the classes?

Comment: @EnsaTouray: no, *especially* because your code allows a different employee number per organization record.  So you have to store the numbers somewhere, may as well be in the same class as the rest of the organization's details.

Comment: what if I were to try and store the numbers inside the organisation records vector along with the other organisation records so that I can implicitly access them when needed? basically I'm not allowed to modify any of the classes

Comment: That is exactly what my answer already does.  The numbers are stored in the records vector, as a field of each record.  If you are asking to store some kind of list of numbers *in addition to* the records *in the same vector*, that will not work, at least not the way you have organized things, unless you store an extra dummy record at the end of the vector with all of the previous numbers formatted as a single delimited string value in one of the existing fields.  But that is a bad design choice. If you can't change the classes, you are SOL without resorting to hacks.

Comment: Can you change the type of the vector? Something like `vector<pair<int,OrganisationRecord>>`?

Comment: @SCFrench: that would require changing the `PayrollProcessing` class, and as Ensa has already stated: "*I'm not allowed to modify any of the classes*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right, somehow I thought it was just OrganisationRecord that couldn't be modified.